# How to show a view created inside the custom tableview cell by swiping the row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created the iPhone app which has the custom tableview cell and I also created a view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Now, when i swiping the the cell in `UITable` the view that i created should be  displayed in the particular cell and all other cell contents should be remained same.

My code as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
RKCardCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RKCardCell"];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[RKCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RKCardCell"];
}
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeMethod:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-320.0, 8.0, 300, 180)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.titleLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.descriptionLabel.text = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//%%% I made the cards pseudo dynamic, so I'm asking the cards to change their frames depending on the height of the cell
cell.cardView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, [((NSNumber*)[cardSizeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])intValue]-10);

return cell;
}
```

Following code is for gesture swiping:

```
- (void)swipeMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRec
{
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
    CGRectOffset(self.rkCardCell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
}];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good if you use the gesture recognizer with the table view.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeTarget:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:_myTableView];
```

And your swipe target method like as follows.

```
- (IBAction)swipeTarget:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint swipePoint         = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:_myTableView];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [_myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipePoint];
    RKCardCell *cell           = [_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

    // Add your code here to show your view
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
           CGRectOffset(cell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank u.. +1 for you.. I have modified your code and then used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell .

It's a really good and simple library to make custom swipable tableviewcell.